# Status bar wrong colour initially and pushing layout off screen slightly

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am working with an activity that has a few different stages. It is designed like a wizard so a few sections of it are tutorial like pages where I hide the toolbar and status bar. The Activity starts off with the toolbar hidden. In each of the fragments, I have an `onToolbarShown(ActionBar ab)` (called in the base fragments `onStart()` method) which I use to edit the title, if the back button shows etc, and then I call the `showToolbar` method below:

```
public void showSystemUi(boolean show){
    if(show){
        KKDeviceUtil.showSystemUI(mRootLayout);
    }else {
        KKDeviceUtil.hideSystemUI(mRootLayout);
    }
}

@Override
public void showToolbar(boolean show){
    if(getSupportActionBar() != null){
        showSystemUi(show);
        if(show) {
            mRootLayout.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
            getSupportActionBar().show();
        }else{
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
            mRootLayout.setFitsSystemWindows(false);
        }
    }
}
```

(`showSystemUi` is the stock show/hide method suggested by android [here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html#nonsticky))

The problem is that the first time I show the toolbar, the status bar is the wrong colour and the layout is shunted down by the height of the status bar. As seen here:

[image: problems]

When I next switch fragments, the problem clears up:

[image: wha?]

And if I go back to the previous fragment, it looks correct:

[image]

I don't get this problem if I never hide the toolbar/system windows in the first place. I originally had some of the operations in a different order and thought that re-arranging them could help, but It didn't seem to make any difference. I also tried calling `setStatusBarColor` but that had no effect. I also have `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/status_bar_color</item>` in my `v21/styles.xml` which is the correct colour for my status bar, and my primaryDark is the same colour as the screenshot (buggy) above shows.

I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong here, is this the correct way to show/hide my toolbar/system ui and why does this only happen on the first showing of the toolbar?

(Note: it is hard to see from the screenshots, but in the first screenshot, the 'Done' button is much closer to the bottom than the correct placing in the third screenshot)

Answer (score -1):

Please see below i've shown you demo style that will reflect color on the status bar.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/side_bar_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/side_bar_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/side_bar_color</item>
</style>
```

There "colorPrimaryDark" is that color which will used at status bar, you need to set this style to your application or activity at manifest class

Comment: Hi. My primary colour is not the same as my status bar colour. The only component I need to be this style is my toolbar. Not the entire app.

Comment: then please change the "colorAccent" and "colorPrimary" because you need to set only "colorPrimaryDark".

Comment: But then in places where I actually use the current primary dark will be incorrect. This doesn't seem to address the actual issue here. I would prefer not hacking around it.

Comment: there you will use color which you want. That android feature i hope you understand. Thanks